# Keras: Implementation of sparse softmax cross entropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a Keras implementation of [this](https://github.com/salesforce/awd-lstm-lm) model. I have put together a data set with around 5 million sequences of length 35 to train the model. With a dictionary size of 50 000 words, the categorical crossentropy implementation in Keras (based on `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`) is very slow, one epoch takes around 12 hours on a Tesla P100 GPU. The most obvious way to speed this up would be to use the sparse softmax cross entropy implementation in Tensorflow.

I wrote a simple custom loss function for this based on a [tutorial](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/21_Machine_Translation.ipynb).

The new custom loss function does speed up the training by a factor of 4, which is fantastic. However, the loss is not decreasing/decreasing very slowly compared to the same number of steps taken with the slow cost function. I was able to reproduce this with some toy data, link below.

[Link to blogpost/notebook](https://erikbrorson.github.io/2018/03/24/Figure-out-problem-with-sparse-cross-softmax/)

It seems that Keras isn't calculating the gradients correctly. I have looked around online but cannot seem to find the reason for this annoying issue. Has anyone faced a similar problem before?

Comment: In your sparse loss, why do you only sum if the output shape is >= 3? You *always* need a scalar value as loss. The `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` output will *not* be scalar. I don't know what exactly happens when you use a non-scalar as a cost but unfortunately Tensorflow does accept it -- the result is most likely garbage.

Comment: This is not the issue since the output that is causing the has rank 3. If you look at the implementation of the built in [Keras loss function](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3018-L3050) it is also clear that this is the way it was implemented. I also checked in my notebook that the cost is correctly calculated, the only thing that is strange is the consistent slower training time (counted in number of epochs before convergence).

Comment: Have you tried using tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss?